# Linq to SQL Nested

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

**I have 3 tables**

> Worker (ID,CodeEm,Name)
>
> Project(ID,ProName,Description)
>
> RetaleTbl(IDworker,IDProject)

When I select a project, I will show workers in selected Project and workers not in selected Project. 
and this code workers in selected Project

```
var selectedPro= from c in db.Worker 
                               from d in db.RetaleTbl
                               where d.IDProject== ID && c.ID == d.IDworker
                               select c;
```

and this code workers not in selected Project (but i have problem with it because RetaleTbl table data have 1 worker do 2 project)

```
var firstFilter= from c in db.Worker 
                               from d in db.RetaleTbl
                               where d.IDProject != ID && c.ID == d.IDworker
                               select c;
```

and now i need one more filter Workers not in `selectedPro`

Comment: Try this `where d.ProName != selectedPro && c.ID == d.IDworker`

Comment: Thank for help me but from d in db.RetaleTbl have not ProName Field and i thinks this can be right but have error var firstFilter= from c in db.Worker 
                               from d in db.RetaleTbl
                               where d.IDProject != ID && c.ID == d.IDworker
                               select c;

Comment: Right, try this `where Project.First(p => p.ID == d.IDProject).ProName  != selectedPro && c.ID == d.IDworker`

Comment: follow you and i receive a error notification is : Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and IQueryable<Worker> can u tell me What does this mean pls ? ty

Comment: Guess error is not in `where` clause. post your whole query.

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
var projectId= 2; // replace with a valid projectID value

var workersNotInProject = db.Worker.Where(c => !(db.RetaleTbl
                                  .Where(s => s.IDProject== projectId)
                                  .Select(d => d.IDWorker))
                         .Contains(c.ID)).ToList();
```

This is basically the LINQ version of the SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM WORKER WHERE ID NOT IN ( SELECT WORKERID FROM RELATETBL WHERE PROJECTID=2 )
```